# iOS GameCenter, AVAsset, and Audio Streaming

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I get a song from the device iTunes library and shove it into an AVAsset:

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    NSArray *arr = mediaItemCollection.items;

    MPMediaItem *song = [arr objectAtIndex:0];

    AVAsset *songAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
}
```

Then I have this Game Center method for receiving data:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
```

I'm having a LOT of trouble figuring out how to send this AVAsset via GameCenter and then have it play on the receiving device.

I've read through:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioStreamReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006162

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW5

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

I am just lost. Information overload.

I've implemented Cocoa With Love's Audio Stream code, but I can't figure out how to take the NSData I receive through GameCenter and shove it into his code.
http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html

Can someone please help me figure this out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the AVAsset is not the actual song. So if you want to send the actual data of the picked song you need to try something like this:

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
{
    NSArray *arr = mediaItemCollection.items;
    MPMediaItem *song = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSData *songData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL]];
    // Send the songData variable trough GameCenter
}
```

On the other device now you need to write the NSData you receive to the disk somewhere and than create an AVAsset with it's newly URL. Like this:

```
- (void)match:(GKMatch *)match didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromPlayer:(NSString *)playerID
{
    NSString *url = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    [url stringByAppendingPathComponent:<#audio_file_name#>];

    // Make sure there is no other file with the same name first
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:url]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:url error:nil];
    }

    [data writeToFile:url atomically:NO];

    AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url] options:nil];

    // Do whatever you want with your new asset
}
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Mihai, I appreciate the code here, but I DO know how to send a file via game center, but my problem is, lets say  a song is 3 megabytes, i don't want to wait until the whole file is sent before I start playing it, I want the 2nd device to stream it. So I suppose I would need to send chunks of data (comprising the whole song) and then parse those chunks and play them on the receiving device.  Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I see where you are going with that. The only thing that I'm pretty sure of is that you can't send the `AVAsset` directly because it doesn't contain the actual song data. So I think the whole GameCenter approach would not be good enough for your need. Try and see if [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/NetworkStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002277-BCIDFCDI) may help you setting up a socket stream between the two iPhones and send the song data like that... Would that be an option for you or GameCenter is the only option?

Comment: I've also found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/InGameVoice/InGameVoice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH104-SW8) which sounds a little bit promising... See what you can do with it!

Comment: I'd be ok not using game center, but my big hurdle then would be finding and connecting to other devices. I wouldn't even know where to start on that.